# Test Material UI <AutoComplete /> with Pupeteer in React for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, puppeteer

I have this [Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) `<AutComplete />` Form

```
        <Autocomplete
          disablePortal={true}
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
            return option.label === value.label;
          }}
          id="foo-bar"
          options={data}
          onChange={...}
          renderInput={(params) => ...}
        />
```

Which I am trying to test like so

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

describe("AutcompleteComponent.js", () => {
  let browser;
  let page;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      slowMo: 500, // slow down by 250ms
      devtools: true,
    });
    page = await browser.newPage();
  });

  it("basic functionality", async () => {
      await page.goto("http://localhost:3000");
      const autocomplete = page.$("#foo-bar");
      const input = page.within(autocomplete).getByRole("combox");
      autocomplete.focus();
      page.fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "Kitten" } });
      page.fireEvent.keyDown(startingAirport, { key: "ArrowDown" });
      page.keyDown(startingAirport, { key: "Enter" });
      expect(input).toHaveValue("Kitten");

  });
});
```

Because I am running it in headless mode, I can see that it opens the site, but it does not focus nor type anything into the `<AutoComplete />` Form.

What is the way to test this?

Comment: Don't you need to `await` all of these async functions or am I missing something when Puppeteer is used in a test suite like this (is there a special package here)?